# Appcelerator WebView Offline Browsing

Tags: android, ios, webview, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to achieve this in Appcelerator Alloy: I would like my users to be able to click a UI button to save a website currently shown in a WebView element for later recall. It should then work offline and include CSS and Images included in the HTML (and CSS) code. Is there any best practice to start off with here? I am targeting iOS and android with this app.

Thank you for your input!
jŒ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will not post code here, but I can tell you what to do, as I coded the same thing a few days ago. But not with Alloy.

You have to download the html content via xhr get or post and save it into a file to the applicationDataDirectory. Then you can access to it completely whenever you want.

Comment: What did you do about the CSS and images included?

Comment: Parsing, downloading, and rewriting I assume?

Comment: yes, you have to replace the external URLs with your internal ones